# How can I make sed delete a line then ignore the test of the file?

Tags: sed

I'm using the following command to extract descriptions from patches:

```
sed '
    s/Title: \(.*\)/### \1 ###\n\n**File:** FILE_NAME_HERE/
    /^diff\|^---/ {
        q
    }
' "$patch" | egrep -v '^(diff|---)'
```

How can I get rid of the `egrep -v '^(diff|---)'` part and only use sed? I tried doing this:

```
/^diff\|^---/ {
    d # <-- This is what I added
    q
}
```

But once that "d" is reached, the "q" gets skipped and the rest of the lines in the body of the patch get printed. Here is a sample patch:

```
Title: Font Array Support

Modifies st to support user-defined fallback fonts specified in an array
defined as `static const char *fonts[]`. This change also resolves an issue
where fallback fonts were used in place of default fonts in an inconsistent
manner which caused identical sets of text to sometimes use different fonts. In
the following example, DejaVu Sans Mono is the primary font with two others
specified as fallbacks:

    static const char *fonts[] = {
        "DejaVu Sans Mono",
        "VL Gothic",
        "WenQuanYi Micro Hei",
    };

diff --git a/st.c b/st.c
index 2594c65..f7973bd 100644
--- a/st.c
+++ b/st.c
@@ -353,10 +353,17 @@ typedef struct {
    FcPattern *pattern;
 } Font;
```

The sed script should return everything above the line that starts with "diff;" this is what the output should be:

```
Title: Font Array Support

Modifies st to support user-defined fallback fonts specified in an array
defined as `static const char *fonts[]`. This change also resolves an issue
where fallback fonts were used in place of default fonts in an inconsistent
manner which caused identical sets of text to sometimes use different fonts. In
the following example, DejaVu Sans Mono is the primary font with two others
specified as fallbacks:

    static const char *fonts[] = {
        "DejaVu Sans Mono",
        "VL Gothic",
        "WenQuanYi Micro Hei",
    };
```

Comment: @John1024, I've added a sample patch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *return everything above the line that starts with "diff;"*

#### Using sed

In that case, try:

```
sed '/^diff/,$d' a.patch
```

The above deletes all lines from the first that matches the regex `^diff` to the last line, `$`.

A slightly more efficient version exits when the line containing `^diff` is reached:

```
sed -n '/^diff/q; p' a.patch
```

Using your sample file:

```
$ sed -n '/^diff/q; p' a.patch
Title: Font Array Support

Modifies st to support user-defined fallback fonts specified in an array
defined as `static const char *fonts[]`. This change also resolves an issue
where fallback fonts were used in place of default fonts in an inconsistent
manner which caused identical sets of text to sometimes use different fonts. In
the following example, DejaVu Sans Mono is the primary font with two others
specified as fallbacks:

    static const char *fonts[] = {
        "DejaVu Sans Mono",
        "VL Gothic",
        "WenQuanYi Micro Hei",
    };
```

#### Using awk

Using awk:

```
awk '/^diff/{exit} 1' a.patch
```

The `1` is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.  However, when the first line that matches the regex `^diff` is reached, the program exits.

```
$ awk '/^diff/{exit} 1' a.patch
Title: Font Array Support

Modifies st to support user-defined fallback fonts specified in an array
defined as `static const char *fonts[]`. This change also resolves an issue
where fallback fonts were used in place of default fonts in an inconsistent
manner which caused identical sets of text to sometimes use different fonts. In
the following example, DejaVu Sans Mono is the primary font with two others
specified as fallbacks:

    static const char *fonts[] = {
        "DejaVu Sans Mono",
        "VL Gothic",
        "WenQuanYi Micro Hei",
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I'm actually comfortable with awk, but I want to get better with sed, and I also find it easier to write portable sed scripts than portable awk scripts likely because I've been spoiled by gawks numerous, useful extensions whereas I rarely find myself yearning for new features when I use sed. In this case, the awk script you posted is perfect portable, but the sed script I posted is a shortened version of what I'm actually using.